# onnx to trt failed - RuntimeError: cannot get YoloLayer_TRT plugin creator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt, ldd, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to run the **YoloV4** (Demo 5) in [TensorRt demos repo](https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos) on AWS ec2.

I created ec2 VM with nvidia-gpu (with AMI - `Amazon Linux 2 AMI with NVIDIA TESLA GPU Driver`),

which has: `NVIDIA-SMI 450.119.01   Driver Version: 450.119.01   CUDA Version: 11.0`.

On this EC2 I pulled and entered into the tensorrt official container, with:

`sudo docker run --gpus all -it -v /home/ec2-user/player-detection:/home nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:20.02-py3 bash`

I did the following steps:

1. Ran `python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` && `python3 -m pip install nvidia-pyindex` && `pip install nvidia-tensorrt`.
2. Inside the `yolo/` folder, I ran:
   `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.
3. `pip3 install onnx==1.9.0`.
4. Inside the `plugins/` folder, I ran `make`.
5. Inside the `yolo/` folder, I ran `./download_yolo.sh` && `python3 yolo_to_onnx.py -m yolov4` && `python3 onnx_to_tensorrt.py -m yolov4`.

I got the following error for the `python3 onnx_to_tensorrt.py -m yolov4` command:

```
 "RuntimeError: cannot get YoloLayer_TRT plugin creator"
```

From reading https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/issues/476 it seems that the problem is related to dynamic libaries.

I tried to view the libaries that I have, and got:

```
$ ldd libyolo_layer.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff142a4000)
    libnvinfer.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so.7 (0x00007f9673734000)
    libcudart.so.11.0 => /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.11.0 (0x00007f96734af000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9673126000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9672f0e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9672b1d000)
    libcudnn.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8 (0x00007f96728f4000)
    libmyelin.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmyelin.so.1 (0x00007f9672074000)
    libnvrtc.so.11.1 => /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so.11.1 (0x00007f966feac000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f966fca4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f966faa0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f966f702000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9699135000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f966f4e3000)
    libcublas.so.11 => /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.11 (0x00007f9668008000)
    libcublasLt.so.11 => /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.11 (0x00007f965a23e000)
```

It seems that I miss some, and also when I tried to print all the plugins, I didn't see the `YoloLayer_TRT`.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution was:**

1. change the image tag to `:21.10-py3` (thx to Hyunwoo Kim!).
2. change the `TENSORRT_INCS` to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/NvInfer*` and `TENSORRT_LIBS` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer*`.
3. changed computes to 70 (in my environment) - you can check your version [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).

Answer (score 1):

Did you load your libyolo_layer.so using ctypes module? It seems that YoloLayer_TRT is custom plugin built by yolo team, and you have to load library file to use it in python.

https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/issues/476#issuecomment-935225260

Comment: Its part of the plugins.py code (https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/blob/master/yolo/plugins.py#L17). I ran "make" in the "plugins/" directory - which created the 'libyolo_layer.so' file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed that part. The problem is maybe about PluginRegistry as the last part of refered page. Actually I've been searching about TRT custom plugins for a few weeks, and my custom plugin was loaded successfully... (I'm using docker. No error in plugin loading and haven't tested yet.) I'll try this in my environment and see if things go different.

Comment: I've followed your way almost same, and I made .trt file successfully. I tested w/ yolov4 and yolov4-416. I ran it from nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrt:21.10-py3 release. Changing container version is unsatisfying but worth a try.

Comment: + I tested it from my own desktop. (Ryzen 3700X, RTX 2070S)

Comment: @HyunwooKim did you changed the Makefile as the x64_84 README mentioned in "Demo #4 (YOLOv3) & Demo #5 (YOLOv4)" (https://github.com/jkjung-avt/tensorrt_demos/blob/master/README_x86.md)? If so what did you put? I guess that your pc is arm, but the container is x86_64. Did you changed the TENSORRT_INCS, TENSORRT_LIBS, compute?

Comment: @Yagel Yes, I changed Makefile as you mentioned, and I didn't see any problem.

Comment: and the architecture of Ryzen processor is x86-64(AMD64), not arm.

Comment: @HyunwooKim that's cool. can you tell me what did you put in the TENSORRT_INCS, TENSORRT_LIBS?

Comment: @HyunwooKim never mind - I succeeded!
 I needed to do few stuff: 1. change the image to 21.10-py3 (thx to you!). 2. change the TENSORRT_INCS to /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/NvInfer* and TENSORRT_LIBS to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer*. 3. changed computes to 70 (in my environment).

Comment: @Yagel Congrats! My TENSORRT_INCS, TENSORRT_LIBS are same as you.